# Circular assignment in R

Tags: r

I found a line the the genetics package that goes like this:

```
P <- D <- Dprime <- nobs <- chisq <- p.value <- corr <- R.2 <- P
```

note `P` is both at the beginning and at the end. What does it mean?

Comment: It sets all of those values to the same value as `P`.  There's no apparent reason for the `P` at the end.  Which file are you looking at?

Comment: it's in the LD.R file

Comment: I should've said, there's no apparent reason for the `P` at the beginning.

Comment: Well after all those assignments, who would not feel like a refreshment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This construct will assign the value of `P` to variables with each of the other names given in the string of `<-`s. That assignment will take place in the current environment.

Thus, if the variable named `P` on the far right is **not** in the current environment, a new variable `P` will be created in the current environment.

To see this in action, run the following from a fresh R session:

```
ls()
# character(0)
mean <- a <- b <- mean
ls()
# [1] "a"    "b"    "mean"
```

Comment: except in this case, `P` is defined immediately before it is assigned to itself.

Comment: Yeah, just looked at that block of code, and in this case, including that `P` on the left does precisely nothing (although it's ultimately harmless). My guess is that it's either an oversight (unlikely), or that it is there as a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: The example is possibly flawed because the user can be assured that there will be an object named 'mean' (namely the function) whereas 'P' is not invariably present in an R workspace.

Comment: @DWin -- Not sure I follow. Are you just saying this kind of assignment only works if the righthand-most object already exists somewhere along the search path? (For the record, in the example given by the OP, from `genetics:::LD.data.frame`, `P` was defined three lines before the displayed code snippet.)

Comment: Right; just saying that if 'P' didn't exist you would get an error, whereas your code would never throw an error.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Can you explain why you deleted your answer to my question about R debugging?  It seemed to work exactly the way I needed it to.

Comment: @Szabolcs -- I had reread your question and noticed that you knew which function you wanted to investigate, so I thought DWin's idea of using `trace()` was perhaps the better fit. Will undelete, though, if you found it useful. Plus, come to think of it, `options(error=recover)` is actually the better option when the offending function might be called many many times before it eventually fails you. Unlike `trace()`, it will only pop into an interactive environment when the error finally occurs.